# In Java when I use ArrayList.get(i) I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to Array Lists and I feel like this question will be a little complicated. I'm trying to make a smart collision detector. The constructor begins a polygon by receiving start coordinates and adding them to each ArrayList. The AddVertex() method adds another set of coordinates to each method and the End() method adds another pair of coordinates at the location of the first coordinate. I then have a method called MouseCollision() which returns a Boolean and tests if the Mouse is inside the polygon. If the points are arranged clockwise it tests if the mouse is inside the shape but if the polygon is created counterclockwise it will test for the mouse in the negative shape. I'm using a system of inequalities to determine if the mouse is on the correct side of the line, it gets a it complicated in that part.

Anyways, this is the full text of Detector.java:

```
    package helpers;

import java.util.*;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;

import static helpers.Artist.*;

public class Detector {

    List<Float> pX, pY, b, m;
    boolean colliding;

    public Detector(float pX, float pY) {;
        this.pX = new ArrayList<Float>();
        this.pY = new ArrayList<Float>();
        this.pX.add(pX);
        this.pY.add(pY);
    }

    public void AddVertex(float pX, float pY) {
        this.pX.add(pX);
        this.pY.add(pY);
    }

    public void End() {
        this.pX.add(pX.get(0));
        this.pY.add(pY.get(0));
    }

    public boolean MouseColliding() {
        colliding = true;
        this.m = new ArrayList<Float>();
        this.b = new ArrayList<Float>();

        for (int i=0; i<pX.size(); i++) {
            if (pX.get(i+1)-pX.get(i) == 0) {
                if (pY.get(i+1)-pY.get(i) > 0) {
                    if (Mouse.getX() >= pX.get(i)) {}
                    else colliding = false;
                } else {
                    if (Mouse.getX() <= pX.get(i)) {}
                    else colliding = false;
                }
            } else {
                m.add(pY.get(i+1) - pY.get(i)/pX.get(i+1) - pX.get(i));
                b.add(pY.get(i) - m.get(i)*pX.get(i));
                if (pX.get(i+1)-pX.get(i) > 0) {
                    if (HEIGHT - Mouse.getY() <= m.get(i)*Mouse.getX()+b.get(i)) {}
                    else colliding = false;
                } else {
                    if (HEIGHT - Mouse.getY() >= m.get(i)*Mouse.getX()+b.get(i)) {}
                    else colliding = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (colliding) return true;
        else return false;
    }


}
```

I also get an error message whenever I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at helpers.Detector.MouseColliding(Detector.java:47)
    at data.Boot.<init>(Boot.java:57)
    at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:72)
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I went to line 47: `b.add(pY.get(i) - m.get(i)*pX.get(i));` And I don't know what the problem is.
I'm knew to ArrayLists, do I need to make an Iterator? And how would I do that?

Comment: If you had *read* the exception instead of just dismissing it as an 'Error' you would practically have the answer.

Comment: array are zero indexed, because you are doing `pX.get(i+1)` you are running into an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) when `i` equals `px.size() - 1`.

Comment: I never heard that called "off-bone" before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to `for (int i=0; i<pX.size()-1; i++) {` iteration should be

`px.size() - 1` so your `pX.get(i+1)` would not cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Comment: Right, because I have 5 points but only 4 lines that I want to call for, problem is, I tried that but I still get the exact same error message. I did a little bit of working with it to see what would happen, and It's kind of interesting. When I subtracted 2, it ran fine, but my collision box didn't work. (By the way, when I subtracted two, my detector had 3 vertexes, one at 0, 0, another at 64, 0 and one more at 64, 64. I also found that if I only had 2 vertexes, and only subtracted one from pX.size(), it would run without crashing, but no matter what I did, the collision detector didn't work.

Comment: I think I'm close to figuring out, and sorry for wasting your time because I'm stupid. Basically, what went wrong is my program tests to make sure that the slope isn't infinity, and does a different method of testing without the slope if that's the case. The problem is, when my program recognizes a infinite slope line, it doesn't give a value for m, so when pX calls for m, it's one step ahead of m, so there's no value for it.

Comment: Ooo that's great you figured out what is problem and don't think you stupid we all are same